# Did the blanket pardon from 'The Three Musketeers' exist in real life?

Tags: france, 17th-century, persona

In his novel *The Three Musketeers*, Dumas describes Richelieu giving the following paper to Milady de Winter:

> C'est par mon ordre et pour le bien de l'Etat que le porteur du
> present a fait ce qu'il a fait.
>
> 3 decembre 1627.
>
> Richelieu

Translated into English:

> Dec. 3, 1627
>
> It is by my order and for the good of the state that the bearer of this has done what he has done.
>
> Richelieu

So my two questions:

1. Is it just a literature, or were these kinds of papers given in the real life of 17th century France?
2. Does the author refer to a particular kind of official paper which could have been given by a cardinal or a first minister to a known set of people according to a law or a custom, or is this *just* a note?

Comment: Can we restrict this question to history, rather than to fiction?  Are there examples of such a note in history?

Comment: It is pointless to argue based on clerical authority or theoretical state structure. First, this is a work of fiction, not a treatise on government, second much of the point of the book and of history is that France was a failed state; the ostensible form of government was completely ineffectual.  Legal (de jure) governance had been replaced by effective (de facto) governance, led by an extra-legal authority.

Comment: @MCW is quite right. Even is a somewhat less failed state such as Tudor England a chief minister could upend the whole country with the King's backing. But if he lost that backing, he could lose his head over a parking ticket.

Answer (score 8):

In 17th century France, the top of the judiciary hierarchy is the King, who is an absolute monarch. Therefore, only a direct order from the King himself would be "legally" allowed to bypass laws and judges; it is called a [*lettre de cachet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettre_de_cachet). We can see, for instance, Louis XIV issuing a bunch of them during the [*affaire des poisons*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affair_of_the_Poisons) (1677 to 1682) as an attempt to quell the scandal when witness statements began to involve the King's principal mistress [Madame de Montespan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ath%C3%A9na%C3%AFs_de_Montespan). Even Louis XIV, at the high tide of his personal absolute power and glory, found it difficult. (See [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2262023867) for a solid relation of that affair; I don't know if it was translated to English.)

From this, we may infer that a note from Richelieu, who was not king (although he had the unfailing political support of Louis XIII), would hardly have had any legal statute, although it could have impressed a provincial guard for enough time to allow a skilled spy to escape. It is also doubtful that a political figure as astute and energetic as Richelieu would have signed such a highly compromising note; Dumas is here writing as a novelist, not as an historian.

Answer (score 3):

I think the previous posters while correct on LEGAL authority are forgetting the influence that the Catholic church had on the populace. Crossing a Cardinal could result in excommunication and in their very antiquated views it would mean that their souls would be damned to hell with no hope of salvation.

It is not unrealistic to believe that the faithful of this time believed that they could have been influenced. The church was selling plenary indulgences and collected tithings. They were very wealthy and powerful. So just because they didn't have the authority to make such a statement. You'd definitely think twice about killing someone with a hall pass from Richelieu. Yeah, you could get away with it, but you'd suffer extreme consequences for it. So yeah, kinda sorta still holds water that it would have worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Richelieu gained status from his church position, but he gained *power* because the king  backed him.

Answer (score -1):

I see nothing special in that the cardinal could give such a letter to facilitate assistance to his envoy.

On the other hand, I am sure that such a letter would not have any legal force in case of trial or charges.

Comment: Do you have sources?

Comment: @Luke there is no need for sources to assert that Cardinal (as any other man) could write such paper. The signature of the cardinal could help the bearer receive assistance from the cardinal's subordinates and friends. This does not give any legal right though because Cardinal was not a sovereign and could not give exemptions from the law.

Comment: In short it is just an accompanying letter addressed to those to whom his authority is important.

Comment: It might not, or it might. We need a source here.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg of course he might, as anybody.

Comment: @Anixx We need a source that says cardinals didn't have powers to give exemptions from the law. In almost all Catholic countries that wasn't the case in the medieval ages --the papal power was paramount to that of the sovereign's in religious matters and cardinals frequently used to bend things so as to make them "religious matters". See also Henry VIII's clash with the pope.

Comment: All this is currently in the realm of speculation, but I would point out that if Richelieu had such powers, they would perhaps have been available to him mainly (and perhaps exclusively) with his chief minister (not his cardinal) [hat on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Richelieu_La_Rochelle_1881_Henri_Motte_1847_1922.jpg) ...